# Laravel error after uploading to AWS

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, was

I built a simple website with **laravel** and it runs fine on my local machine. However, when I upload it to the **AWS** only one page gives me errors!

The error message:

```
Undefined offset: 1 (View: /var/app/current/resources/views/admin.blade.php)
```

The other error:

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

After some debugging, I found out this code causes the error:

```
<?php
     // visitors number
     $q = DB::table('visitors')->select('visitors')->get(); 
     $t = "$q";
     $r = explode(":", $t);
     $nr = explode("}", $r[1]);
     $vis = $nr[0];

     // sub number
     $q = DB::table('visitors')->select('sub_visitors')->get(); 
     $t = "$q";
     $r = explode(":", $t);
     $nr = explode("}", $r[1]);
     $sub = $nr[0]; 
?>
```

I know it is not the best practice to put the `php` code inside the `view` but I am a beginner in laravel and I was in a hurry. And the explode method because the results was in a format like `json` (I don't think that it was `json`).  How can I solve it in this way.

Comment: What is the error message? What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: @Jerodev sorry I just noticed that I didn't put the error message , anyway I updated the question and the error is now visible

Comment: You shouldn't manually break up an object from a json string, what exactly are you trying to achieve with this code? Are you getting a field from the database?

Comment: @Jerodev yes I have a visitors counter and a conversion counter (how many visitors have filled a form in the home page) but if it works on the local machine why it is not working on the AWS?

Comment: Possibly because the field does not exist in your database. Can you post what your database looks like, then I can help you to properly get the data from your database.

Comment: @Jerodev if the problem was with the field then the home page wouldn't work because it increments the number of visitors if the visitor is new

Comment: General advice: Dont write database queries in your template files. And dont convert your collection-object to a string, and dont explode that string into an array, and dont explode the array-values into new arrays to search for a value that may or may not exist. This code you provided is so bad practice, that you should delete it right away and go back to reading about collections in laravel and general development patterns.

Comment: Please post a sample output or explain what you are trying to achieve..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not Json and you dont need to explode it, those are objects of class
you can use it like this to access a particular column(visitors in your case) of your result

```
$q = DB::table('visitors')->select('visitors')->get();
foreach($q as $item){
   echo $item->visitors;
}
```